# Why does my solution for the quantum harmonic oscillator blow up?

Tags: c++, physics, numerical-methods, ode, odeint

I am using odeint to solve for the energy levels of the QHO (Griffiths problem 2.55).

I am integrating from x=0 to x=3. When I plot the results, I expect to see half of a gaussian with a tail that explodes towards positive or negative infinity, depending on whether I set the energy parameter to be above or below a valid energy level.

Instead, my solution blows up to positive infinity right away, and will not show any other behavior.

Here is my code, including my derivation of the system of ODEs in a comment:

```
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include "print.hpp"

namespace ode = boost::numeric::odeint;

//constexpr auto ℏ = 6.582119569e-16; // eV·Hz⁻¹
constexpr auto ℏ = 1.0;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  constexpr static auto mass = 1.0;
  constexpr static auto frequency = 2.0;
  constexpr static auto energy = 0.99 * 0.5*ℏ*frequency;

  const auto& m = mass;
  const auto& ω = frequency;
  const auto& Ε = energy;

  using State = std::vector<double>;

  auto Ψ₀ = State{ 1.0, 0.0 };
  auto x₀ = 0.0;
  auto x₁ = 3.0;
  auto Δ₀x = 1e-2;

  ode::integrate(
      [](const State& q, State& dqdx, const double x) {
        // convert schrödinger eqn into system of 1st order ode:
        // (-ℏ²/2m)(∂²Ψ/∂x) + ½mω²x²Ψ = EΨ
        // ⇒ { (-ℏ²/2m)(∂Ψ'/∂x) + ½mω²x²Ψ = EΨ
        //   , ψ' = ∂Ψ/∂x
        //   }
        // ⇒ { ∂Ψ'/∂x = (EΨ - ½mω²x²Ψ)/(-ℏ²/2m)
        //   , ∂Ψ/∂x = ψ'
        //   }
        // ⇒ { ∂Ψ'/∂x = ((E-½mω²x²)/(-ℏ²/2m))Ψ
        //   , ∂Ψ/∂x = Ψ'
        //   }
        auto& dΨdx = dqdx[0];
        auto& d²Ψdx² = dqdx[1];

        const auto& Ψ = q[0];

        dΨdx = q[1];
        d²Ψdx² = (std::pow(m*ω*x/ℏ, 2) - Ε) * Ψ;
      },
      Ψ₀,
      x₀, x₁, Δ₀x,
      [](const auto& q, auto x) {
        std::cout << x << " → " << q << std::endl;
      });
}
```

Here is some example output:

```
    x                        Ψ          Ψ'
    0                        1         0
    0.01                     0.999951  -0.0098985
    0.055                    0.998506  -0.0542012
    0.2575                   0.968801  -0.229886
    0.406848                 0.927982  -0.306824
    0.552841                 0.881662  -0.315318
    0.698835                 0.839878  -0.242402
    0.825922                 0.817189  -0.101718
    0.953009                 0.817616  0.124082
    1.0801                   0.853256  0.457388
    1.20718                  0.940137  0.939688
    1.31092                  1.06489   1.495
    1.41925                  1.26832   2.30939
    1.50629                  1.50698   3.22125
    1.59738                  1.85714   4.54112
    1.67542                  2.2693    6.10168
    1.75345                  2.82426   8.23418
    1.83149                  3.57561   11.1845
    1.89812                  4.42976   14.6191
    1.96476                  5.55      19.2346
    2.03139                  7.02934   25.4872
    2.09803                  8.99722   34.0259
    2.15585                  11.2396   43.9977
    2.21367                  14.1481   57.2333
    2.2715                   17.9436   74.9054
    2.32932                  22.9271   98.6414
    2.38714                  29.5111   130.712
    2.43818                  37.1021   168.461
    2.48922                  46.9104   218.185
    2.54026                  59.6467   283.99
    2.5913                   76.2675   371.487
    2.64234                  98.0659   488.377
    2.69338                  126.798   645.271
    2.73898                  160.271   831.155
    2.78458                  203.477   1074.9
    2.83018                  259.47    1395.74
    2.87578                  332.33    1819.67
    2.92138                  427.52    2381.96
    2.96698                  552.389   3130.66
    3                        666.846   3825.59
```

Why does the output not match my expectations?

edit: here is an ascii version of the code in case anyone has issues with unicode:

```
    #include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <vector>
    
    namespace ode = boost::numeric::odeint;

    constexpr auto hbar = 1.0;

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
      constexpr static auto mass = 1.0;
      constexpr static auto frequency = 2.0;
      constexpr static auto energy = 0.99 * 0.5*hbar*frequency;

      using State = std::vector<double>;

      auto state_init = State{ 1.0, 0.0 };
      auto x_init = 0.0;
      auto x_final = 3.0;
      auto x_step_init = 1e-2;

      ode::integrate(
          [](const State& q, State& dqdx, const double x) {
            auto& dPsi_dx = dqdx[0];
            auto& d2Psi_dx2 = dqdx[1];

            const auto& psi = q[0];

            dPsi_dx = q[1];
            d2Psi_dx2 = (std::pow(mass*frequency*x/hbar, 2) - energy) * psi;
          },
          state_init,
          x_init, x_final, x_step_init,
          [](const auto& q, auto x) {
            std::cout << x << ", " << q[0] << "," << q[1] << std::endl;
          });
    }
```

Comment: I, for one, applaud your brave use of Unicode for your program.  Break the chains of ASCII!  *Freedom!*

Comment: What I normally do is work out the first few iterations step by step on paper and then step through the program looking for where the program doesn't match my expectations. Then, if the problem's not immediately obvious from what went wrong, I'll break down the errant line further to see where in that line things went sideways.

Comment: @Eljay `auto& d²Ψdx² = dqdx[1];` -- Still, the OP should be careful about posting source code that contains non-ASCII characters.  Others who would like to compile the code may have issues with their source code editor not recognizing such symbols.

Comment: I'm impressed, I thought only ANSI character set was allowed for variable names.

Comment: FYI, the expression `(x * x)` is often more efficient than calling `pow(x, 2)`.  The multiplication may be more accurate too.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie point taken, edited and added an ascii version

Comment: Note:  I wasn't being sarcastic, I really do like your Unicode version.  The project I work on, my coworkers are strictly ASCII and against Unicode.  Even though all six of our platforms, the compilers are Unicode savvy.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks, I prefer the unicode as well, especially for math/physics. I'm only disappointed that I can't use tickmarks in C++ identifiers like I can in Haskell.

Comment: I wonder what non-standards compliant compiler works with Unicode? (3 guesses, first two don't count...) But I applaud the work there. We need non-English speaking coders as well.

Comment: On the topic: Did you, in inserting the tabulated energy levels, remember to rescale the energy to `E = E/(-ℏ²/2m)`? If `E` is too small, the exponential regime dominates, you need `E` large enough to have an initial oscillating segment with roots before the square term grows too large.

Comment: @LutzLehmann That did the trick! Though I did have to drop the - sign from the expression, otherwise it yields negative energy. Could you expand this comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: cΔΔl lΔΔking cΔde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a coding error but an error in transforming the equations. After the last equation you have in the comments, you need another step

```
 ⇒  ∂²Ψ/∂x² = (EΨ - ½mω²x²Ψ)/(-ℏ²/2m)
 ⇒  ∂²Ψ/∂x² = ((mωx)²-2mE/ℏ²)Ψ
```

Note that the constant in the factor is different from the one you use in code.

---

Mathematically, `y''=C·(x²-a²)` is in an oscillating regime for `|x|<a` and in an exponential regime for `|x|>a`. The oscillating frequency depends on the size of the factor `C·(a²-x²)`, so if `a` is small the frequency is small and the wave length can be larger than `2a` so that there is no guarantee for a root. For `a` large enough the frequency around `x=0` will become large enough so that zeros close to `x=0` are guaranteed. Somewhere in-between is the lowest energy of an eigenstate.

By omitting the factor the energy used was shifted below the lowest eigenstate, so that only the exponential behavior was visible.